# How do blind people cook?

Tags: accessibility, physical, kitchen

How can, could, and how do currently blind people cook without burning themselves? I mean, what kind of user interface is good for them?

One thing I can think of, is they should have a table that goes all around them, thus giving them ample space. Some tables must have holes about 12cm deep of various shapes for holding bottles, glasses, and shallower holes for holding plates of various kind. How to use it: simple: prop the bottle, or plate, on the surface, till it sticks in. Easy to pull out without dropping it.
Have a 40cm-wide 50cm-tall wooden vertical barrier separating the portion of the table eith hot tools, and the one with cold tools. Have yet another barrier for storing sharp objects (knives, sharp lids, slicers, shredders, blades, etc.).

Comment: Interesting [stovetop for blind](https://www.behance.net/gallery/15975835/Ocuelo-Stovetop-for-the-Blind) proposal here to give some ideas EDIT: I guess none of those take care of the burning problem, for that I suppose they use thier spatial awareness and sound of cooking food. And presumably some oven mitts.

Comment: You don't have to 'see' heat. You can feel it.

Comment: Do not cook blind people!

Comment: The 'stovetop for the blind' illustrates the more general principle that things which are designed for people with accessibility problems - are often better designed for fully able people.

Comment: @PhillipW Please do *not* make me use a stove with 3-heat settings. Or a glass top, for that matter. *Better* remains a subjective judgement.

Comment: Fair enough on the 3 heat settings: although what the interface actually needs are 'target heats' - so if you want it to bring to the boil and then automatically turn down to simmer, the electronics are clever enough to do this for you without your intervention.

Comment: @plainclothes, what are your objections to blind people cooking?

Comment: That blind stovetop seems dangerous. The buttons are on the same surface as and surrounded by the heating elements. Let's just stick with dials on the front of the stove instead of the top surface..

Comment: @JackMaddington No sense of humor ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blind people adjust to the surrounding environment and use tools that can be managed without seeing with their eyes. Some use their hands to feel how well a burger is cooked by using different "sensors" of their hand.

You'll get the feeling of blind people cooking from this video: [How blind people cook food alone](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=umiOuVA7PEc)

Comment: Seriously, how do they "adjust". Even on a fireless stove, things get "hot". The bottom of the stove, the pots, the plastic handles of pots which could melt, the water inside the (which could also burn) pots, forks and spoons used to stir (and it is also difficult to handle a spoon with gloves), the oven door can get slightly hot, as well as the inside, of course. If they come into contact with these, they may not have a second chance with having the same untraumatized hand (or arm, leg, or whatever).

Comment: Also, a pot, if used, should have, for hearing blind people, a thermometer with a timer which goes off when the pot is safe to touch. Only in this way, the pot can safely be carried from the stove to the sink (and washed).

Comment: The fireless (eg., electric) stove could also have ridges, in the shape of a "+" separating the four stoves (like the x an y -axes separating the four quadrants, with one quadrant per stove "fire"), so that when a pot is placed on the stove it falls into the right quadrant, thus receiving a fair amount of fire (imagine if the stove was new; I don't think you could know how far the stove "fires" were (from each other), in some other way). Any ideas?

Comment: @JackMaddington what does being able to see have to do with knowing when you can pick up a hot pot? Heat isn't visual on a pot. Whether one can see or not, they have the same challenge in figuring out if a pot is too hot to touch.

Comment: @JackMaddington I looked at the video and I saw a blind person make a burger with fries. Did you see it or are you after something else? Is not the response you wanted? If so, please clarify your question.

Comment: True, not all pots turn red when hot, some will display bubbles from the vapor, and if you put your hand close you can feel the heat, but, unfortunately, most people don't have the precision in their movements to stay away from the hot pot and pull their hand away from the hot zone when the heat is starting to get felt but before touching the pot.

Comment: What about a glove which fits inside a metallic hand with heat sensors. The sensors vibrate or make a sound when the heat is encountered; they could even emit a note whose pitch indicates the temperature, perhaps simultaneously with a voice reading the temperature from the sensors. That way the person will know if the pot is safe to touch with the bare hands.

Comment: @BennySkogberg, please give me an answer.

Comment: "sensors vibrate or make a sound when the heat is encountered" = I think you're over-engineering here.

Comment: @JackMaddington, Benny gave you an answer, whether you like it or not, is not necessary to harass him with all the questions you may have. And remember he's not being paid to answer you, it's out of his good will (like everybody else here). If you have a different question, please open a new one and hopefully someone will answer it